# Error about use IKImageBrowserView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ikimagebrowserview, imagekit

I use 4 IKImageBrowserView in my App. Every time I go to a view which contain a IKImageBrowserView, console will show these three line error:

```
invalid share context
invalid context
--ImageKit Error: IKVRamMAnager::unable to create a shared context
```

I google for some time but found nothing.
Somebody can tell me how to solve these error? 
Thanks;

By the way, the IKImageBrowserView work fine in most situation. But when I want to custom  its Appearance like the [official example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ImageBrowserViewAppearance/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009013-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), it has many strange problem. I am pretty the problem cause by that three line error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have already done this, but you need to add Quartz.framework in your application. Quartz framework contains ImageKit framework which is required for IKImageBrowserView.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already add Quartz.framework to my application. Thanks anyway.